# High-quality question closed and deleted before I had time to respond

Tags: discussion

About a week or so ago I asked and answered [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/1579409/how-to-configure-and-deploy-to-amazon-s3-via-aws-cli) on using the AWS command line tool. I put a lot of work and effort into the answer, and was highly surprised to find that it got closed as off-topic.

Yes, its subject matter is AWS, but the question and the answer were primarily about documenting how to use the AWS CLI tool to perform the vast majority of the deployment, only resorting to the web app where necessary.

In any case, life got in the way since, and before I could even get round to asking this meta question, my question was deleted.

On what basis was the question closed as off-topic in the first place, and why was it deleted so quickly?

Comment: it was auto deleted https://superuser.com/help/roomba ("question was closed more than 9 days ago"  criteria)

Comment: Configuring and setting up websites is off topic for [su]

Comment: The reason the question was closed appears in the close reason.  **This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.** Question was automatically deleted due to the state of the question (no upvotes) and the fact the answer also had no upvotes.  The tag description clearly indicates what AWS questions are within scope.